# Materialize with Array as DataSource

Tags: javascript, materialize

Estoy usando la función autocompletar de *materialize*, ¿Cómo hacer para utilizar un *JSON* local y llenar un `select` a partir de este?, En la documentación oficial, hay uno solo utilizando un objeto.

```
data: {
    "Apple": "null",
    "Microsoft": "null",
    "Google": "http://placehold.it/250x250"
}
```

... y lo que quiero utilizar es algo parecido a esto...

```
data: [{
    "field": "null",
    "field2": "a",
    "field3": "b",
    "field4": "c"
},
{
    "field": "null",
    "field2": "a",
    "field3": "b",
    "field4": "c"
},
{
    "field": "null",
    "field2": "a",
    "field3": "b",
    "field4": "c"
}]
```

... pero no funciona, ya intento formateando la información a `value`, `label`, así como en *jQueryUI*, pero tampoco funciona...

```
var prog = $.map(this._programasService.getProgramas(), function (i)
{
    return {
        label: i.field2,
        value: i.field3
    };
});
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres lograr? o ¿cual es el resultado que deseas obtener? los datos de tu arreglo son los mismos en cualquier caso.

Answer (score 1):

Al final termine por construir un objeto con lo que necesitaba ya que cada valor en mi caso es unico

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.programas = this._programasService.getProgramas();

    var program = $.map(this._programasService.getProgramas(), function (i)
    {
        return {
            id: i.prgprg_descripcion,
            text: i.prgprg_nombre
        };
    });

    var arr = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < program.length; i++)
    {
        arr[program[i].id] = program[i].text;
    }


    $(this.el2.nativeElement).autocomplete({
        data: arr
    });
}
```

Comment: Está muy bien que hayas regresado y publicado como respuesta tu solución. Tu pregunta tiene 3 respuestas pero ninguna aceptada todavía, aunque no es obligatorio, podría decirse que te falta aceptar una.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a meter un array dentro de un campo del primer array JSON?

Por ejemplo:

```
data: [{
    "field1": "null",
    "field2": "a",
    "field3": "b",
    "newData": [{
                "field": "null",
                "field2": "a",
                "field3": "b",
                "field4": "c"
               }]
}]
```

Ten en cuenta que en newData podrías insertar todos los arrays que necesites  claro.

Después podrías acceder de esta forma:

```
label: i.newData.field2 ;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como ya habéis comentado, el parámetro data del plugin jQuery autocomplete de materialize necesita un objeto clave-valor.

En cuanto a la transformación del modelo con el que trabajas, puedes utilizar [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para evitar recorrer el array dos veces y generar un código más compacto.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.programas = this._programasService.getProgramas();

    var data = this.programas.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue){
        accumulator[currentValue.pgrpgr_descripcion] = currentValue.pgrpgr_nombre;
        return accumulator;
    }, {});

    $(this.el2.nativeElement).autocomplete({
        data: data
    });
}
```

Nota: Tanto [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) como reduce están ampliamente soportados, por lo que podrías utilizarlos en lugar de la función de jQuery.